# Dependency update with dagger 2

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2

Being me a newbie with dagger, i'm failing to realize how to update a dependency with dagger 2.
Let's say I have a paginated list via RecyclerView and Jetpack paging. I want to get a data from the `fragment` to the `PageKeyedDataSource`.

```kotlin
class DataSource() : PageKeyedDataSource<Int, Model>(){

    override fun loadInitial(
        params: LoadInitialParams<Int>,
        callback: LoadInitialCallback<Int, Model>
    ){
         val dateParams = MyApplication.appComponent.dateParams()
         val response = executeRequest(
             dateParams.minDate, 
             dateParams.maxDate,
             1, 
             params.requestedLoadSize)
         ...
    }

    override fun loadBefore(params: LoadParams<Int>, callback: LoadCallback<Int, Model>) {
        //nothing
    }

    override fun loadAfter(params: LoadParams<Int>, callback: LoadCallback<Int, Model>){
        val dateParams = MyApplication.appComponent.dateParams()
        val response = executeRequest(
            dateParams.minDate, 
            dateParams.maxDate,
            1, 
            params.requestedLoadSize)
        ...
    }

}
```

`Application` and `Component`:

```kotlin
class MyApplication : Application() {
    companion object{
        val appComponent: ApplicationComponent =
            DaggerApplicationComponent
            .builder()
            .dateParamsModule(dateParamsModule())
            .build()
    }
}
```

```kotlin
@Component(modules = [DateParamsModule::class])
interface ApplicationComponent{
    fun dateParams(): DateParams
    fun inject(dep: DataSource)
}
```

`Module` and `DateParams`:

```kotlin
data class DateParams(
    var minDate: String = "", 
    var maxDate: String= "")
```

```kotlin
@Module
class DateParamsModule {

    @Provides
    fun dateParams():DateParams{
        return DateParams()
    }
}
```

so all right ...
But, let's say that from a date filter I want to modify the injection, inserting a minimum and maximum date. So from the fragment how do I change the injection?
Thanks

Comment: 2 options. Either use scopes or runtime definitions which can be achieved by injecting a factory, instead of the object, you can use `@AssistedInject` . https://github.com/square/AssistedInject

Comment: Could you give me an example with `@Scope`

Comment: check `Singletons and Scoped Bindings` here https://dagger.dev/dev-guide/